# new not working in function block of node-red

Tags: node.js, node-modules, node-red

I am trying to use [nodes7](https://github.com/plcpeople/nodeS7) in a function block, as [s7](https://github.com/netsmarttech/node-red-contrib-s7/tree/55df7289d835bfd21e15383fc628bf1a8d44f8de) did not suffice for my purpose (nodes7 is underlying library used by s7).

The example given in nodes7, works fine as an independent node application. The code is given below.

```
var nodes7 = require('nodes7');  // This is the package name, if the repository is cloned you may need to require 'nodeS7' with uppercase S
var conn = new nodes7;
var doneReading = false;
var doneWriting = false;

var variables = { TEST1: 'MR4',         // Memory real at MD4
          TEST2: 'M32.2',       // Bit at M32.2
          TEST3: 'M20.0',       // Bit at M20.0
          TEST4: 'DB1,REAL0.20',    // Array of 20 values in DB1
          TEST5: 'DB1,REAL4',       // Single real value
          TEST6: 'DB1,REAL8',       // Another single real value
          TEST7: 'DB1,INT12.2',     // Two integer value array
          TEST8: 'DB1,LREAL4'       // Single 8-byte real value
};

conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '192.168.0.2', rack: 0, slot: 1}, connected); // slot 2 for 300/400, slot 1 for 1200/1500
//conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '192.168.0.2', localTSAP: 0x0100, remoteTSAP: 0x0200, timeout: 8000}, connected); // local and remote TSAP can also be directly specified instead.  The timeout option specifies the TCP timeout.

function connected(err) {
    if (typeof(err) !== "undefined") {
        // We have an error.  Maybe the PLC is not reachable.
        console.log(err);
        process.exit();
    }
    conn.setTranslationCB(function(tag) {return variables[tag];});  // This sets the "translation" to allow us to work with object names
    conn.addItems(['TEST1', 'TEST4']);
    conn.addItems('TEST6');
//  conn.removeItems(['TEST2', 'TEST3']);  // We could do this.
//  conn.writeItems(['TEST5', 'TEST6'], [ 867.5309, 9 ], valuesWritten);  // You can write an array of items as well.
    conn.writeItems('TEST7', [ 666, 777 ], valuesWritten);  // You can write a single array item too.
    conn.readAllItems(valuesReady);
}

function valuesReady(anythingBad, values) {
    if (anythingBad) { console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG READING VALUES!!!!"); }
    console.log(values);
    doneReading = true;
    if (doneWriting) { process.exit(); }
}

function valuesWritten(anythingBad) {
    if (anythingBad) { console.log("SOMETHING WENT WRONG WRITING VALUES!!!!"); }
    console.log("Done writing.");
    doneWriting = true;
    if (doneReading) { process.exit(); }
}
```

However, I am unable to use this in function block. I have included the nodes7 as below as advised by the node-red community while requiring additional package

```
    functionGlobalContext: {
        nodes7:require('nodes7')
        // os:require('os'),
        // jfive:require("johnny-five"),
        // j5board:require("johnny-five").Board({repl:false})
    },
```

However my code breaks when I construct the object as below as given in example.

```
var conn = new nodes7;
```

I have tried `var conn = new nodes7();` also but in vain. I am getting the below error.

```
"TypeError: nodes7 is not a constructor"
```

So the nodes7 variable is referenced properly, but node-red complaints its not a constructor. how do I then go ahead. Below is my whole function block code throwing above error.

```
var nodes7 = global.get('nodes7');
var conn = new nodes7();

conn.initiateConnection({port: 102, host: '127.0.0.1', rack: 0, slot: 1}, connected); // slot 2 for 300/400, slot 1 for 1200/1500
node.log('This worked');

function connected(err) 
{
    if (typeof(err) !== "undefined") 
    {
        // We have an error.  Maybe the PLC is not reachable.
        node.log('Connection not successful');
    }

}

return msg;
```

If helps, I have just used an inject node before and a debug node after, just to observe. I am newbie to node-red. Please help.

[image]

#### Update 1:

As requested by one user, I inserted `node.warn(nodes7)` before calling constructor and observe that it is undefined. But why? I am using global.get, installed in proper directly (I could see in node_modules folder of node-red) still this happens.

[image]

#### Update 2

I updated the settings.js file as in usr directory but still getting the same response as undefined. Please find below pics.

Locating the settings.js file..

[image]

Navigating to that file...

[image]

Updating that file by opening vs code there..

[image]

Installed nodes7 and then and restarting node-red, I still get same error.. below is the code..

[image]

#### Update 3

My update 2 works after closing all, and restarting..

Comment: where did you install the `node7` npm module?

Comment: Insert `node.warn(node7);` before `var conn = new nodes7();` do you get a yellow message in the sidebar with `undefined`?

Comment: I installed using `npm install nodes7` in the node-red installation directory... `%AppData%/Roaming/npm`.. It went to the node_modules folder as expected..so I wonder why this is not working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NPM modules referenced from the `settings.js` in the `functionGlobalContext` need to be installed in the `userDir` because they are loaded relative to the active `settings.js` file.

Both the `userDIR` and `settings.js` file that are in use are logged in the first few lines of output when Node-RED starts up.

You should only be editing the `settings.js` file in the `userDir`. The version in the Node-RED install dir is only used when setting up new `userDir`'s. You will also need to restart Node-RED when ever you edit this file.

Comment: I did that there also, still I get the same error `Undefined`..

Comment: What about checking which `settings.js` you edited?

Comment: yeah did all, and still got the same error.. :(  pl check my updated question with screenshots..

Comment: I closed and restarted.. it seems to be working now.. at least the object is recognized.. thanks :)